# How do you determine if the current user is logged into Azure AD in .NET Core 3.1

Tags: .net-core, azure-active-directory, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a .NET Core 3.1 program that hosts an Angular 9 app that will be used by users in a company that uses Azure AD.  I need to determine if the user is already logged into their Azure AD and if so get some information about them.  I would like to determine this before the Angular App is loaded for the user.  This is pretty straight-forward in standard Windows AD and .NET but I can't find how to do this with .NET Core and Azure AD.

I've added some pseudo code below to help give an idea of what I'm trying to achieve:

```
[ApiController]
[Authorize]
[Route("api/[controller]/[action]")]
public class AuthenticationController : ControllerBase
{
    public AuthenticationController()
    {

    }


    [AllowAnonymous]
    [HttpPost]
    public LoginResult Login([FromBody] LoginRequestDC loginRequest)
    {
        LoginResult lr = new LoginResult();

        if (loginRequest != null)
        {
            try
            {
                if(NotLoggedInAzureAD)
        {
                    lr = LoginWithUserNameAndPasswordAndGetInfoFromDataBase(loginRequest);
        }
        else
        {
        lr.IsLoggedIn = true;
        lr.UserInfo = GetInfoFromAzureAD;
        }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Common.AppLogger.Error(ex, $"Unable to login.");
            }
        }

        return lr;
    }

private bool NotLoggedInAzureAD()
{
    //Not sure how you would get the Azure AD user in .net core 
    return CodeToAskAzureADIfUserLoggedIn(MyHttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name);
}

private UserInfo GetInfoFromAzureAD()
{
    return CodeToAskAzureADForUserInfo(MyHttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name);
}
 }
```

Please help.

Comment: Please add some code or pseudo-code. Your current description is unclear. When do you want to check Azure AD? How user is logged? Application is web api or Blazor or razor or web mvc?

Comment: I found documentation about Azure AD, but I don't know details yet - I'm learning too: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/azure-active-directory/?view=aspnetcore-5.0.

Answer (score 2):

Check out the [Code Samples page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/sample-v2-code). There are a lot of samples, for example .NET Core Web App. Like [this one](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-aspnetcore-webapp-openidconnect-v2/blob/master/1-WebApp-OIDC/1-1-MyOrg/README.md), which is a .NET Core 3.1.

But I suggest that you first start with [Authentication basics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/authentication-vs-authorization), go over [Security Tokens](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/security-tokens), the [Application Model](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/application-model) and finally understand the [App Sign-In Flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/app-sign-in-flow) in Microsoft Identity Platform.